# SimplePanel can only contain one child widget

Tags: gwt, panel, children

When i run the following Code and push Button "Push", more than once a time, i get browser error "simplePanel can only contain one child widget". How can i solve that problem? thank you in advance! Jogi

```
public class Projekt implements EntryPoint {

    private RootPanel rootPanel;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        rootPanel = RootPanel.get("gwtContainer");
        rootPanel.setSize("1902", "868");

         final AbsolutePanel boundaryPanel = new AbsolutePanel();
         boundaryPanel.setStyleName("frame1");
         boundaryPanel.setSize("1455px", "600px");       

         final Diagram diagram = new Diagram(boundaryPanel);

         RootPanel.get().add(boundaryPanel, 446, 242);


         final Connector con = new Connector(100, 300, 300, 500);

         Button la = new Button("Push");
         la.setSize("200", "200");
         RootPanel.get().add(la);

         Button la2 = new Button("Push2");
         la2.setSize("200", "200");
         RootPanel.get().add(la2);

         final Image img = new Image("images/concrete.svg");
         img.setSize("200", "200");


         final Shape shapei = new Shape(img);


         Image img2 = new Image("images/variable.svg");
         img2.setSize("200", "200");
         boundaryPanel.add(img2, 200,200);

         final Shape shapei2 = new Shape(img2);
         shapei2.showOnDiagram(diagram);

         la.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                 boundaryPanel.add(img, 100,100);
                 shapei.showOnDiagram(diagram);
            }

         });
         la2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                     con.showOnDiagram(diagram);
                }

             });


         diagram.addDiagramListener(new DiagramListenerAdapter() {

              @Override
              public void onElementConnect(ElementConnectEvent event) {
                if (con.startEndPoint.isGluedToConnectionPoint()) {
                    Widget connected = con.startEndPoint.gluedConnectionPoint.parentWidget;
                    if(connected.equals(shapei.connectedWidget)){
                  Image logo = new Image("images/xor.svg");
                  logo.setSize("100", "100");
                  boundaryPanel.add(logo);
                }
                    else if(connected.equals(shapei2.connectedWidget)){
                         Image logo2 = new Image("images/and.svg");
                      logo2.setSize("100", "100");
                      boundaryPanel.add(logo2);
                    };
              }}
            });

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RootPanel.get()` is a SimplePanel. You try to add more than one child to it, resulting in this error.

Instead, you should add HTMLPanel, for example, to your RootPanel, and then add all the children to this HTMLPanel.

Comment: hmm..but i do not add the widgets to the RootPanel, rather to the boundaryPanel(AbsolutePanel) and it is  the single child of the RootPanel? I

Comment: Look at your own code: `RootPanel.get().add(la);`, then `RootPanel.get().add(la2);`.

Comment: okay so i checked that again, and this is not the problem. The Error occurs when i click the button la.

Comment: the problem is inside the clickevent...img and shapei are final, and when i click the button for a secondtime the error occurs. how can i bypass to use final?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your Diagram extends GWT's **SimplePanel**
 class? SimplePanel can contain only a single widget, have a look here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html

You could either extend a different class, or call the **remove(Widget w)** method to remove the existing widget before trying to add a new one.

Comment: Diagram is an absolutePanel and i can not remove the widgets, because i need them :(